# Exclude records in AVG SQL function? (can't use WHERE in main query because of another count)

Tags: sql, db2, average

my SQL query which works fine is

```
select case month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))
        when 1 then 'January'
        when 2 then 'February'
        when 3 then 'March'
        when 4 then 'April'
        when 5 then 'May'
        when 6 then 'Jun'
        when 7 then 'July'
        when 8 then 'August'
        when 9 then 'September' 
        when 10 then 'October'
        when 11 then 'November'
        when 12 then 'December'
    end as Month, 

    count (case when service='ADSL' then 1 end) as  ADSL,
  AVG (timestampdiff(
  4, 
  char(actualfinish - reportdate))/60.00) as efficiecny



from INCIDENT
where   year(STATUSDATE) = year(current_timestamp) 
group by month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))
```

I want to get for each month number of services with ADSL (it is done through the first COUNT)
and average time difference in hours for the records which do not have service ADSL. So I must exclude in the AVG function all records with service ADSL but I can not put it in where clause

```
 where   year(STATUSDATE) = year(current_timestamp) and service!='ADSL'
```

because my COUNT function needs to  have service='ADSL'

How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Avg() aggregate function ignores nulls](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000758.htm), you can set expression to null if service is 'ADSL'. Avg() will then ignore those records.

```
   AVG (case when service != 'ADSL'
             then timestampdiff(4, char(actualfinish - reportdate))/60.00) 
             else null
         end) as efficiency
```

You could try with [coalesce](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Ffcoal.htm):

```
   COALESCE (AVG (case when service != 'ADSL'
             then timestampdiff(4, char(actualfinish - reportdate))/60.00) 
             else null
         end), 0) as efficiency
```

Comment: Zdravo Nikola, hvala ti ovo izgleda daje tacan rezultat(provericu jos malo) ali da li posto za jedan mesec dobijam vrednost null da li mogu nekako da za tu vrednost dobijem 0. Zato sto mi je potrebno za iscrtavanje grafika da postoji neka vrednost. Hvala

Comment: Zdravo Dejane, molim te pogledaj dopunjeni odgovor.

Comment: Nikola nazalost nesto me zeza. Dobijam rezultat 0E-18 . Ne znam kako ovo moze negativno da utice na iscrtavanje grafika

Comment: @Dejan Ne bi trebalo imati veze s ovim gore. Da li dobijaš isti rezultat kad dodaš `and service!='ADSL'` u where i vratiš originalni AVG()?

Comment: Zdravo. U tom slucaju ne dobijam ovaj rezultat 0E-18 . Dobijam OK rezultat u tom slucaju jedino sto mi tada ne prebroji ADSL servise.

Comment: A sada, kad vratiš coalesce i makneš `and service!='ADSL'` ako promijeniš 0 u npr. 100, da li dobiješ neku zbunjujuću brojku?

Comment: radi u BIRT-u lepo prikazuje 0 i sa onim COALESCE... . hvala Nikola puno...mozes samo da mi kazes sta radi ova funkcija nisam je vidjao pre? hvala,POZDRAV!!!!

Comment: Ćao Dejane, drago mi je što smo uspjeli. Za [coalesce](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Ffcoal.htm) imaš link gore, a ukratko on vraća prvi not null iz liste parametara; ako AVG() vrati neku brojku onda daje tu brojku, ako vrati null onda nulu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's some trick you can use to do this all in one query, but these should really be two separate queries, one counting ADSL, and one doing the average of non-ADSL.  If you really want to do it in one round trip, you could do a pair of subqueries, then join the subqueries on the month.  The whole thing will be a lot more readable, faster, easier to maintain, plus more canonical SQL.

Also, looks like DB2 has a built-in function to return the name of the month, MONTHNAME: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000831.html

---

Well, since you insist...I'm not super familiar with db2, so the syntax may be a little off, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT avgt.month, countt.data, avgt.data FROM

(SELECT month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)) AS month,count(*) AS data FROM INCIDENT WHERE year(statusdate) = year(current_timestamp) AND service='ADSL' GROUP BY month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))) AS countt

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)) as month,avg(...) AS data FROM INCIDENT WHERE year(statusdate) = year(current_timestamp) AND service!='ADSL' GROUP BY month(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))) AS avgt

ON avgt.month=countt.month
```

Another way to do it may be to have a case within the AVG that gives NULL if service='ADSL'.  It's not super clear from the documentation of AVG what it does with NULL values, but it'd be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I really need this in one query.Do u know the way maybe? Because I need to display that results in ONE table in some REPORTS

Comment: It is almost correct but not exactly. Current result is  April 1; 6.4  May 0, 800   Correct result will be  April 1; 0  May 0; 800 first column is ADSL, second efficiency  but using your query I am gettin empty result because they are not bind with ON. because of 0 values in that months. I suppose it needs just a little correction

Answer (score 0):

Calculate `AVG` salary excluding `min()` and `max()` salaries in a table.

```
select round(avg(table.salary),2) from table
where table.salary NOT IN ((select min(salary) from table), (select max(salary) from table))
```